# Find equation of the Nine Point Circle of Triangle ABC.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

In $\Delta ABC  ,  m\angle ABC = 90 .$
Let $S$ be the circumcircle of $ \Delta ABC .$

$ S : x^2+y^2=25 .$
Tangent with negative slope from $(11,-2)$ touches $S$ at $B$.

Find equation of the Nine POint Circle of $\Delta ABC$

I figured out the logic to the problem but I can not understand how to get the co-ordinates of $B$.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint.

Try to explain the following.

Let $B(a,b).$

Hence, we need to solve the following system:
$$a^2+b^2=25$$ and
$$\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{b+2}{a-11}=-1.$$